# Beyond compare as merge tool on P4 Eclipse plugin

Tags: merge, perforce, beyondcompare, p4eclipse

I'm trying to configure the P4Eclipse plugin (2014.1.965331) to use Beyond Compare as external Merge tool.

I have configured the Bcomp.exe as Perforce Merge in Perferences -> Team -> Perforce ->External Tools. so right now when resolve is requested it's opens the Beyond compare, but without the content of the files.

I know there is a list of arguments that needed to be passed (in P4V it's passed in the argument line as %1 %2 %b %r), as documented here : [Using Beyond Compare with Version Control Systems](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs)

But no luck with the arguments, the trick for adding the arguments is to create a .bat file that calles to Bcomp.exe with additional arguments and set external merge toll to run the .bat file.

Is there any chance to configure it to work fine with beyond compare. (for now only 2 way merge is requested)

Comment: To clarify: you have Beyond Compare working successfully from P4V, but you are having trouble configuring it to work successfully from the P4Eclipse plugin in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, the p4v instructions are documented by Beyond compare team. For the plugin its bot working and not documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of arguments is fixed in the P4Eclipse code.

You're right, you're going to have to write a .bat/.cmd to adjust the parameter list.

P4Eclipse code is in our workshop.

The class that runs the command:

https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/projects/perforce-software-p4eclipse/files/2014-1/src/3.7/plugins/com.perforce.team.ui/src/com/perforce/team/ui/p4merge/MergeRunner.java

Note method getBuilder() that makes the argument list.  The constructor too.  That's what we've got for documentation right now.

What it passes to the constructor depends on what you're doing  - like merge vs diff.

For example, see the "new MergeRunner(...)" in

https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/projects/perforce-software-p4eclipse/files/2014-1/src/3.7/plugins/com.perforce.team.ui/src/com/perforce/team/ui/p4merge/P4MergeResolveAction.java